# server IIS PHP UNC PATH stop working (is_file(),file_extist()) with share folders

Tags: php, iis-7.5, unc

A php application working on windows IIS server (Active Directory), need to read a shared file on different server.
"the site" have windows authentication.

it worked for years. Suddenly last week (22-25 March 2023) stop working.
Now php app reads only internal files (in the same server).

Nothing has changed. Permission of shared files are the same. The user can access to the file with file explorer

I'm searching an advice to try to understand what happened.
Thanks.

Comment: (1) Please define what you mean by "stop working". You said need to read a shared file on different server, so just ONE single file ?? (2) please check your server log and see what errors are recorded when the php app tries to read the particular shared file.

Comment: `Nothing has changed`...unlikely. things that were working before don't just stop for no reason. Computers are quite predictable.

Comment: Now, when I try to read the file (checking first), if(is_file('//NAMEOFTHESERVER_ORADDRESS/folder/file.tx')) func(); 
the risult is false...

I used host name but I tried to move to ip (this way I avoid eventually dns problmes).

Comment: Now, when I try to read the file (checking first), if(is_file('//NAMEOFTHESERVER_OR_IPADDRESS/folder/file.txt')) func(); the risult is false... I used host name but I've tried to move it to IP (this way I avoid eventually dns problmes).

Comment: its works I 've tested several time in the past. You can use either
'//NAMEOFTHESERVER_OR_IPADDRESS/folder/file.txt' 
 or 
"\\\NAMEOFTHESERVER_OR_IPADDRESS\folder\file.txt" both of them.
I made all possible test. but, because I receive a false and not  error I can't verify what kind of problem it is

Comment: If the application was working fine before and suddenly stops, some changes to the system or network may be causing the problem. Check for any recent updates or modifications to your system or network, including updates to your Windows or IIS server, changes to your Active Directory configuration, or changes to file server permissions. In addition, are all shared files unreadable, or only a specific file file.txt unreadable?

Comment: Yes infact I think so. Anyway all shared files are involved.  The same  files are readable from file explorer but not by php.  this probably rules out Active Directory, permissionons, net ecc.

It remains just automaticly updates of SO. But I don't think that is a good thinks remove   security monthly quality rollup of march.
For now I made a change into the app and to the process that create and managed the involved files of data, I moved them in the same server of the app.  But that's definitely not a good thing

Comment: For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, the best way is to use failed request tracking, it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.
This link provide the method to enable [failed request tracing](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.) to capture the detailed error.